# Strongswan VPN Established but no Packets Routed

Tags: routing, cisco-asa, strongswan

I'm setting up a VPN using strongSwan between a Linux instance on an Amazon EC2 instance and a remote network via its Cisco concentrator.
I need to route packets from the Linux instance itself a machine in the remote subnet.

The connection is established OK, but no packets are routed.

I think I need to set up some specific routing rules, how should I go about doing that?

## Software

- Linux kernel 3.5.0-41,
- Ubuntu 12.10,
- strongSwan 5.1.1 (built from source),
- iptables - no rules.

## Network

### Local

- Amazon Elastic IP: 56.x.x.x
- Public facing LAN IP: 172.x.x.x
- Local virtual subnet: 10.254.0.0/16
- Local virtual IP: 10.254.5.174

### Remote

- Public IP of Cisco concentrator: 62.x.x.x
- Remote subnet: 10.192.0.0/12

## Configuration

### ipsec.conf

```
config setup

conn %default
    keyexchange = ikev1
    type = tunnel
    ikelifetime = 86400
    keylife = 28800
    keyingtries = %forever
    esp = 3des-sha
    ike = 3des-md5-modp1024
    forceencaps = yes
    leftauth = psk
    rightauth = psk

conn myconnection
    left = 172.x.x.x
    leftsubnet = 10.254.0.0/16
    leftsourceip = 10.254.5.174
    leftfirewall = yes
    right = 62.x.x.x
    rightsubnet = 10.192.0.0/12
    auto = route

include /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.conf.inc
```

### strongswan.conf

```
charon {
    cisco_unity             = yes
    install_routes          = yes
    install_virtual_ip      = yes
    threads                 = 16
    plugins {
        sql {
            loglevel = -1
        }
    }

    filelog {
        /var/log/charon.log {
            time_format = %b %e %T
            default = 3
            flush_line = yes
        }
    }
}

pluto {
}

libstrongswan {
}
```

## ipsec statusall

```
# ipsec statusall
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.1.1, Linux 3.5.0-41-generic, x86_64):
  uptime: 4 days, since Jan 22 14:24:08 2014
  malloc: sbrk 270336, mmap 0, used 222672, free 47664
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 3445
  loaded plugins: charon aes des rc2 sha1 sha2 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem fips-prf gmp xcbc cmac hmac attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default stroke updown xauth-generic
Listening IP addresses:
  172.x.x.x
  54.x.x.x
Connections:
    smsbrick:  172.x.x.x...62.x.x.x  IKEv1
    smsbrick:   local:  [172.x.x.x] uses pre-shared key authentication
    smsbrick:   remote: [62.x.x.x] uses pre-shared key authentication
    smsbrick:   child:  10.254.0.0/16 === 10.192.0.0/12 TUNNEL
Routed Connections:
    smsbrick{1}:  ROUTED, TUNNEL
    smsbrick{1}:   10.254.0.0/16 === 10.192.0.0/12 
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
    smsbrick[8150]: ESTABLISHED 1 second ago,    172.x.x.x[172.x.x.x]...62.x.x.x[62.x.x.x]
    smsbrick[8150]: IKEv1 SPIs: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_i* xxxxxxxxxxxxx_r, pre-shared key reauthentication in 23 hours
    smsbrick[8150]: IKE proposal: 3DES_CBC/HMAC_MD5_96/PRF_HMAC_MD5/MODP_1024
    smsbrick[8150]: Tasks queued: QUICK_MODE 
    smsbrick[8150]: Tasks active: MODE_CONFIG
```

## ip xfrm

```
# ip xfrm policy
src 10.192.0.0/12 dst 10.254.0.0/16 
        dir fwd priority 3987 
        tmpl src 62.x.x.x dst 172.x.x.x
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 10.192.0.0/12 dst 10.254.0.0/16 
        dir in priority 3987 
        tmpl src 62.x.x.x dst 172.x.x.x
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 10.254.0.0/16 dst 10.192.0.0/12 
        dir out priority 3987 
        tmpl src 172.x.x.x dst 62.x.x.x
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket out priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket out priority 0
```

Comment: The connection is **not** established. The connection seems to be stuck during Mode Config (because you configured _leftsourceip_), check the log on both sides for details (most likely the Cisco peer doesn't expect a Mode Config exchange). Did you already have a look at the [strongSwan wiki](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/AwsVpc)?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to necropost on the topic, there's just not much info out there in one place on this particular configuration in terms of troubleshooting.

My config:

- AWS: Strongswan 5.1.3
- Corp: Cisco ASA5520 8.4(4)1

Symptoms:

1. Could initiate tunnel and ping from Cisco ASA private LAN to AWS private LAN always.
2. On tunnel timeout/restart I could not initiate or ping from AWS to Cisco ASA unless/until traffic was generated from Cisco ASA side. `IPSEC STATUSALL` revealed

   > ```
   > Tasks active: MODE_CONFIG
   > Tasks queued: QUICK_MODE
   > ```

I found that with `modeconfig=push` and `leftsourceip=` both configured, it got stuck at:

> ```
> Tasks active: MODE_CONFIG
> Tasks queued: QUICK_MODE
> ```

Removing `modeconfig=push` left it stuck at:

> ```
> Tasks active: MODE_CONFIG
> ```

Removing `leftsourceip=` did the trick and everything was up and stable both ways.

I take it those two are needed by PIX an maybe some older version of ASA but not this one.